# STM32F4 accelerometer

Tags: c, accelerometer, stm32f4discovery

I need to read some data from accelerometer LIS3DSH in STM32F4 Discovery. I have this main code:

```
uint8_t writeData(uint8_t data) {

    while(SPI_I2S_GetFlagStatus(SPI1, SPI_I2S_FLAG_BSY) == SET)
        ;
    SPI_I2S_SendData(SPI1, data);

    while(SPI_I2S_GetFlagStatus(SPI1, SPI_I2S_FLAG_BSY) == SET)
        ;
    return SPI_I2S_ReceiveData(SPI1);
}

void setReg(uint8_t address, uint8_t value) {
    GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOE,GPIO_Pin_3);
    writeData(address);
    writeData(value);
    GPIO_SetBits(GPIOE,GPIO_Pin_3);
}

uint8_t getReg(uint8_t address) {
    uint8_t data=0;
    address|=(1<<7);
    GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOE,GPIO_Pin_3);
    writeData(address);
    data = writeData(0x00);
    GPIO_SetBits(GPIOE,GPIO_Pin_3);
    return data;
}

int main(void)
{
    char str[4];

    usart_init(); 
    spi_init(); 

    // Turn on accelerometer
    //setReg(LIS302DL_CTRL_REG1, (1<<PD_CTRL_REG1) );
    LIS3DSH_Init();

    // Read data from three registers
    // and write it to UART
    while(1)
    {
        delay();

        itoa((int8_t) LIS3DSH_Get_X_Out(1),&str);
        send_str(&str);
        send_str(":");
        itoa((int8_t) getReg(LIS302DL_OUT_Y),&str);
        send_str(&str);
        send_str(":");
        itoa((int8_t) getReg(LIS302DL_OUT_Z),&str);
        send_str(&str);
        send_str(" | ");
    }
}
```

But it recieves only first value. For example:

```
5:32:128|5:32:128|5:32:128|5:32:128|5:32:128|5:32:128|5:32:128|5:32:128|5:32:128|5:32:128|
5:32:128|5:32:128|5:32:128|5:32:128|5:32:128|5:32:128|5:32:128|5:32:128|5:32:128|5:32:128|
5:32:128|5:32:128|
```

I use USART2 for reading this data. Can somebody say how to update data in real time? For example if I turn over the board the data will change?

Comment: Maybe you are overrinding value in str ...

Comment: @MarkoFrelih no, the function getReg returns this non-changed value

Comment: @MarkoFrelih I found the problem. The power of sensor was not turned on. It solves in register settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. The power of sensor was not turned on. It solves in register settings (0x2). Thanks everybody for help.

Answer (score 0):

We could start searching the error here everywhere. There are some things that are confusing me tho in your question.

1. You are saying you are using **uart2** but are initilating the **spi**.
2. You are using a library [LIS3DSH_lib](http://www.coocox.org/driver_comp/lis3dsh-c1156.html?mc=1&sc=1) which already provides **LIS3DSH_Get_Y_Out** etc.. So why do you use getreg??? Just do it like with the x coordinate.
3. In the lib that I found the spi init is made in the **LIS3DSH_Init()**. So throw your own spi init **out of there**.
4. Make sure you have a LIS3DSH and then dont use **LIS302DL_OUT_Z** macros. The new discoveries use the **LIS302DL**. In case you have a LIS302DL use [this lib](http://mikrocontroller.bplaced.net/wordpress/?page_id=705). I can assure that this one works.

Solution: Try to use [This lib](http://www.coocox.org/driver_comp/lis3dsh-c1156.html?mc=1&sc=1) and throw out all get reg and set reg code and your other spi_init.

Something like that:

```
#include LIS3DSH.h
int main(void)
{
    char str[4];

    usart_init(); 
    LIS3DSH_Init();

    while(1)
    {
        delay();

        itoa((int8_t) LIS3DSH_Get_X_Out(1),&str);
        send_str(&str);
        send_str(":");
        itoa((int8_t) LIS3DSH_Get_Y_Out(1),&str);
        send_str(&str);
        send_str(":");
        itoa((int8_t) LIS3DSH_Get_Z_Out(1),&str);
        send_str(&str);
        send_str(" | ");
    }
}
```